# Не получается ввести данные в БД на русском

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-core-mvc

При попытке ввода на английском данные заносятся нормально. Но если поле `ФИО` или `адрес` на русском, то ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
A database operation failed while processing the request.
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
MySqlException: Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x84\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB2...' for column '_address' at row 1 
MySqlException: Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x84\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB2...' for column '_address' at row 1 
Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this issue
There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been applied to the database

20181228023404_ssd
Apply Migrations

In Visual Studio, you can use the Package Manager Console to apply pending migrations to the database:

PM> Update-Database
Alternatively, you can apply pending migrations from a command prompt at your project directory:

> dotnet ef database update
```

Советы, описанные в ошибке, пробовал делать но не помогает. Диспетчер пакетов пишет, что данные уже существуют (что я в MySql отчетливо вижу).

Сюда ввожу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за того что ваша база данных не понимает кодировку, попробуйте

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```